# git: Output of git cherry does not change after git cherry-pick

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick, git-cherry

I have two remotes in git, namely '**origin**' and '**upstream**'. origin was forked off upstream at some point, and both have had several commits since the fork. Now I want to bring over many (but not all) of the commits that have occurred on 'upstream' to 'origin'. So my sequence of operation is as follows:-

1- Fetch all the changes from the remote repositories and update local master (I'm on the master branch):-

```
git fetch origin
git fetch upstream
git rebase origin/master
```

2- List the difference in commits between local master and upstream's master:-

```
git cherry -v master upstream/master
```

After seeing that I see that there are many commits with the (+) sign:-

```
+ abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd First different commit
+ 123412341234123412341234123412341234 Second different commit
+ efabefabefabefabefabefabefabefabefab Third different commit
+ 567856785678567856785678567856785678 Fourth different commit
+ a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1 Fifth different commit
```

3- I'm interested in cherry-picking the fourth commit, so I proceed with the following command (ensuring that I am on branch master first):-

```
git cherry-pick 567856785678567856785678567856785678
```

4- At this point, I perform git cherry again as listed in step 2:-

```
git cherry -v master upstream/master
```

I expected the output would be different because the Fourth commit would have (-). However, the output after this command is still the same:-

```
+ abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd First different commit
+ 123412341234123412341234123412341234 Second different commit
+ efabefabefabefabefabefabefabefabefab Third different commit
+ 567856785678567856785678567856785678 Fourth different commit
+ a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1 Fifth different commit
```

I have double checked my log in master and I can see that the Fourth commit has been added. Is there something else I need to do in order to see the change in the git cherry output? What do I need to do in order to properly get the difference between **origin/master** and **upstream/master**?

I am using git on Windows version 2.11.0.windows.1.

Comment: The `+` before `56785678` should become a `-` and the line won’t be removed. Are you sure it’s still a `+` after cherry-pick?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I still see the (+).I'll update the question.

Comment: Do `git show` on the commit you cherrypicked and the resulting commit to see why git doesn't recognize they're the same.  As @nnovich-OK points out, if you resolved merge conflicts (merge means merging diffs, there's two sets of changes to merge in a cherrypick, from the old parent to the cherrypick and from the old parent to the new parent) the resulting commit will certainly not have the same changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when cherry-picked commit has conflicts with your branch, so you need to resolve them by adjusting code changes. As a result, `git cherry` can't figure out, that new commit is identical to its originator, so it shows original commit in the list of changes to be applied. [This post](https://dan.bravender.net/2011/10/20/Why_cherry-picking_should_not_be_part_of_a_normal_git_workflow.html) touches described situation. Note, that post isn't fully accurate as described in comments below it.